# RW.DESIGNATOR_FOR_NON_POD Coverity warning

Tags: c++

Why it is bad when a designator is not a pod type?

```
struct Pair
{
    std::string a;
    std::string b;
};

Pair pair = { 
   .b = "B" // RW.DESIGNATOR_FOR_NON_POD "class type not suitable for use with designators"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

POD types usually don't have any weird stuff going on like hidden pointers, private class members or offsets associated with them which makes them behave like a **C** type.

The the compiler is simply warning that something **magical** can happen if you do this.

Comment: That's clear that non-pod types have more complicated construction. But why do we have warning for designated initialization, but doesn't have for assignment initialization for example? It looks like due to the fact that "designated initialization" came from C language, it is supposed to be used with pod types only.